# jQuery plugin for cross browser css compatibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css, cross-browser

In my app users will be able to change element's border style attributes like radius, color, width, style etc.

Now I also need to be able to get these attributes with jQuery, however in order to get something like border-radius, you need to use `css("border-top-left-radius")` (at least in new versions of firefox and chrome) and this will not work in all browsers, so my question is:

**Is there a plugin that adds correct prefix to the css selector like webkit, moz etc. and maybe also makes these css features cross-browser compatible when setting these attributes?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree) by [Lea Verou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90826/lea-verou) offers a [jQuery plugin](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/#jquery) that simply integrates the -prefix-free script itself with jQuery's `.css()` method.

All the script itself does is add vendor prefixes to CSS properties where appropriate so you don't have to. It doesn't do anything else like polyfills.

Comment: Yeah, I did found that plugin, but was just curious if there was anything "all in one" type of plugin. I will accept your answer if no one offers anything better :) Thanks!