# Simple way to combine the three CSS classes for -moz, -webkit, and regular?

Tags: css, cross-browser

It gets really annoying, especially when using these techniques as much as I am, to not only add these, but then to change them even the slightest, because I have to do it three times, rather than just once.

Example:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius:5px;
```

There must be some way to only have to do this once, a plugin or something.

Comment: How about [a jQuery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142690/jquery-plugin-for-cross-browser-css-compatibility) (for what is essentially a standalone script)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a CSS preprocesser like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). The mixin capability allows something like this:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
    -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
    -moz-border-radius: $radius;
     border-radius: $radius;
}
```

Then you can just reference the mixin like this:

```
@include border-radius(5px);
```

Comment: Or use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). It includes a ton of [CSS3](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) mixins baked in, including [`border-radius`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/border_radius/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a plugin called **prefix-free**

Check this http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Answer (score 1):

you can use [less](http://www.lesscss.com)

or use [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

and I prefer  Less because it more simple and easiest

Comment: In what ways do you find LESS easier than SASS?